# After editing the site-url in wp-config file i cant access the wp-admin area anymore - how to fix it?

Tags: wordpress, url, dns

I wanted to change my siteurl from the ip-address to a domain and added these two lines to my wp-config:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://my-url.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://my-url.com');
```

and these two to my functions.php of my theme:

```
update_option('siteurl','http://my-url.com');
update_option('home','http://my-url.com');
```

Now the site doesnt work anymore. And I cant access the the wp dashboard. So how am I able to change the site url?

Edit: Now i added the lines again. this time with my server-ip-address. Now i can access wp-dashboard but there is a blank page in the frontend.

Regards

Comment: What happens if you undo your changes and just make the change in the admin screen (http://your-url.com/wp/wp-admin/options-general.php)?

Comment: Also, it's possible there are a lot of other places you'll need to update your server (eg URLs in posts).  Might be worth using the database search and replace script mentioned [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#When_Your_Domain_Name_or_URLs_Change).  Make sure you back up your database first though!

Comment: After changing the settings to default by define site url as server-ip everything was like before. The I tried to change in general settings and had the same problem as before - i coudnt access the dashboard. That's really strange. I dont wanna have that site with showing the server ip instead of the domain :(

Comment: In that case, go through the steps in the codex page I mentioned in my last comment.  I've moved servers/domain names quite a few times, and it seems to be the best way - it updates all the references in the database, which should be all you need to do.  Just make sure you can roll back your changes if need be (ie take a backup before you start)

Comment: Wow. To change the url to the domain name is way more complicated than expected ...

Comment: If you're comfortable running the search and replace script, it's fairly quick and easy.  The problem is that references get added to many places in the database over time, so it's not enough to just update the `siteurl` and `home` settings.

Comment: ok. thank you, I'll give it a try. But first I have to find out how to backup my database. Should install phpmyadmin first :D